# How to make multiple pages in the electron application in the Quasar framework?

Tags: javascript, electron, quasar

I'm trying to add a second page to the app.
quasar dev - the page opens normally, but if you run
quasar dev -m electron, the link is no longer working, error cannot get
How can I add a second page to electron using the quasar framework?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't want to post this question, here is the solution:

```
  <q-btn
    @click="$router.replace('/read')"
    icon-right="home"
    >
    Go home
  </q-btn>
```